# While implementing media queries to make site responsive for touch displays, How to remove :hover effects from it?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, vite

I am trying to make my portfolio site responsive for mobile and tab displays... I have a bunch on :hover effects, by default some elements are hidden and show up when cursor hovers on it, like on project card. It's a work in progress and I am working on the navbar.
[CodeSandbox link to project](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mjshubham21/Mjshubham21Portfolio/draft/quizzical-platform?create=true&file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FApp.jsx)

I wanna keep :hover only on desktop or non-touch screen displays, how do I undo :hover on touch displays?

Answer (score 0):

First - on mobile :hover doesn't exist because user doesn't use coursor. You have :hover effect after touching element

Second - you can just set default behavior on mobile resolutions, i.ex.

```
button.custom {
  background-color: green;
}

button.custom:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  button.custom, button.custom:hover {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```